# Gradle Gripe Converting POM to Gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to convert Maven Eclipse project to Gradle Android.  Gradle docs are clear. Goto master pom directory and : gradle init

BUT WHAT REALLY HAPPENS IS:

BUILD FAILED! Could not Convert Maven to POM

Java.lang.NullPointerException

For a build tool to report back a null pointer exception is disgusting!  I mean if you cannot convert the file don't convert it and tell us why!!!  Where is the WHY?

This problem was reported back in 2013 : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-setupbuild-exception/2494

Ok, not everything can be converted but where on earth is the WHY?  I have used --debug and --stacktrace.  All I get is its the converter, a line number and null pointer exception.  Worthless!  Tells me nothing about what Gradle did not like or why it did not like it!  So much for helping ease configuration!

OK, so the question is how do I generate the Gradle file by hand?  Does anyone how know the steps to convert a pom file that goes to maven repo into gradle?

Update: I found this: http://sgeb.io/articles/how-to-migrate-a-simple-android-app-from-maven-to-gradle/

For hand migration.  Any other suggestions?

I've got POM sections like this:

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <output.file.name>${output.file.name.prefix}_LOCAL</output.file> <remote.soap.end.point>http://ipaddr:8080/EP2/</remote.soap.end.point> -->
            <remote.soap.end.point>http://ipaddr:8088/EP/</remote.soap.end.point>
            <skip.proguard>true</skip.proguard>
            <dev.mode>true</dev.mode>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Any docs on Grade DSL for this?

How about exclusions I've got them in spades:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${android.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <!-- <exclusion> <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId> </exclusion> -->
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

How about the parent? the main artifactId?  What do I do with these?:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!-- ================================================================================== -->
<!-- Basic informations -->
<!-- ================================================================================== -->
<artifactId>main_art_id/artifactId>
<packaging>apk</packaging>

<!-- ================================================================================== -->
<!-- Module informations -->
<!-- ================================================================================== -->
<name>mymoduleName</name> 

<parent>
    <groupId>com.mygroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-set</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<!-- ================================================================================== -->
<!-- Properties informations -->
<!-- ================================================================================== -->
<properties>

    <!-- Using with jaxb-api. -->
    <android.dex.coreLibrary>true</android.dex.coreLibrary>
```

I'm ok with snarly RTFM comments, but really where in the manual does it say how to deal with each of these items above?

Comment: "*how do I generate the Gradle file by hand?*" ... well, you could, for example, learn the Gradle domain specific language and then create a Gradle build using your Maven .pom as a template.  Just a thought.

Comment: Provide something that is reproducible, perhaps a copy of your pom?

Comment: Well do I do about exclusions?  My file has lots of exclusions.